# How to sort two things in Java?

Tags: java, sorting

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Employee> unsorted = loadEmployee("NameList.csv", 100);


    Collections.sort(unsorted,(Employee o2, Employee o1)-> o1.getFirstName().compareTo(o2.getFirstName() ));


    unsorted.forEach((Employee)-> System.out.println(Employee));
```

This prints first name in alphabetical order. But how do you sort first name first then by ID?
I have `Employee` class and have `String ID, String firstName`. 
Learning `Collections.sort`here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: @ErnestKiwele That doesn't look like a duplicate to me, as it only sorts by a single field and not multiple.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`Comparator#thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-):

With `Collections#sort`:

```
List<Employee> unsorted = loadEmployee("NameList.csv", 100);

Collections.sort(unsorted, Comparator.comparing(Employee::getFirstName)
                                     .thenComparing(Employee::getId));

unsorted.forEach(System.out::println);
```

With a stream:

```
loadEmployee("NameList.csv", 100).stream()
                                 .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getFirstName)
                                                   .thenComparing(Employee::getId))
                                 .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This sorts first by the `Employee`'s first name and, if two of the names for different `Employee`s are equivalent, it sorts by ID.